# VNC to VM shows a black screen

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, vmware, vnc

I'm working under Windows 7, running VMWare (Workstation 7) and I have an Ubuntu VM. I have set up a VNC hook in the VM settings. Trouble is, when I try to connect to is via VNC, it connects just fine (accepts my password, opens a window), but the screen is solid black. I noticed this happens when the OS locks.

When I view the VM from VMWare it looks just fine - and when I unlock it, the VNC starts to work. This is fine when I have access to the host machine, but what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off screen locking and the screensaver from the settings menu.